# Is there a way to search an element of a vector<String>, then check if it contains a particular char, if it does print it

Tags: c++

The final element in the vector is the char to search for.
Here’s my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
vector<string> words;
string in;
while(cin>>in)
{
words.push_back(in);
}
int size = words.size()
string check = words.at(size-1);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question and provide some context. Why do you need to search if you already know it is the last element you are looking for? It is a `std::vector<std::string>` but you keep mentioning `char`s.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The final element in the vector is a `string`, not a `char`. Can you give us an example with a couple of hard-coded values (i.e. no `cin`)?

Comment: When you ask for help - do you think the helper has _good_ information? What you currently show does not compile, so perhaps people trying to help wont do as good as they would had you provided them with enough input.

Comment: `int size = words.size() string check = words.at(size-1);` can be simplified to `string check = words.back();`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the loop was infinite. Try asking a set number of words then use the find method for each string. Here's an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string in;
    cout << "Enter 5 words: \n";
    for (int i{0}; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Word: ";
        cin >> in;
        words.push_back(in);
    }
    cout << "What character do you want to search for? ";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    for (auto word : words)
    {
        if (word.find(c) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Character \"" << c << "\" found in " << word << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I noticed that you tried to use int to store the size for the string. Use size_t instead. I also think you meant to use the length method of the string, which also returns size_t.